# Identifiability in Parameter Estimation Problem

Tags: estimation, identifiability

I have a question regarding the identifiability of parameters. I know that if $f(y;\theta)=f(y;\theta')$ then  $\theta = \theta'$, otherwise it would be impossible to estimate $\theta$.

However, here is my question: let's say we have a PDF of

$f(y;\theta_1+\theta_2)$

then $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are not individually identifiable by the definition. However if I can find $g(y;\theta_1)=E_{\theta_2}[f(y;\theta_1+\theta_2)]$, then is $\theta_1$ now identifiable?

In other words if we have an unidentifiable problem because  a single parameter of the density function $\theta$ depends on two different parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ can we turn this into an identifiable problem by averaging out one of the parameters?

Comment: That's not always going to give you an identifiable model (tough in most cases it should) and it seems completely fine to me

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeDehaene. In which case wouldn't be unidentifiable?

Comment: Try to find a counter-example yourself. Assume the $\theta$ are angles (between $[0,2\pi]$)